# Segue from UISplitViewController Detail to Master When Master is a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I want to segue from the detail (a map view) to the first tab within the master (a UITabBarController) when an annotation callout is selected.  This first tab is a table view that I want to update.

If I segue to the table view and use a segue style of 'replace' then I lose the tab bar.  If I choose 'push' I get a runtime error that the receiver is not a navigation controller.

I guess I could segue to the tab bar controller, set a boolean on the map view and then drop through the segues to catch up to where I want to be (the table view) or use the app delegate, but I'd like a more elegant solution if one is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirement correctly you have a UITabBarController with some tabs, that then wants to push a detail (map) view on top of it temporarily. When the map view is dismissed, you would like to go back to the same initial UITabBarController?

To do this, the better solution would be to push the map view as a "Modal" - in this case it would take over the screen. Just be careful as you cannot dismiss the modal screen from itself - it needs to be ideally dismissed from the viewcontroller that showed it in the first place. For example in the prepareForSegue method of the class that pushes the modal view controller you can pass a reference back to itself or use a delegate :

```
[modalViewController setParent:self];
```

Then within the modal class, when some button or other event triggers the dismissal, you can have:

```
[parent.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I want to update the master from the detail, using a segue.  I do not want to push the detail (Map View) onto the master.